# Dynamically Add Markers to Google Map from URL in JSON

Tags: json, ajax, google-maps

I am needing a way to dynamically add markers to Google Map, based-on geo-coordinates (latitude/ longitude) stored in an external JSON file.  The method would need to call a url to display a custom marker for each location.  The end goal is to display a weather-specific icon for each location, depending on the conditions observed.

I already have one JSON call to display weather information in a map window (see below):

```
function initMap() {
    var hc = {lat: 40.466442, lng: -85.362709};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: hc
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: obj
    });

    var iconBase = "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/cloudy.gif";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: hc,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hartford City',
            icon: iconBase
        });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

var downloadJSON = function() {
    $.getJSON( "ajax/GeoObs.json?_="+new Date().getTime(), function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Station: " + data.features[0].properties.Station + "</li>");
        items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Time: " + data.features[0].properties.Time + "</li>");
        items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Weather: " + data.features[0].properties.Weather + "</li>");
        items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Temp: " + data.features[0].properties.Temp + "</li>");
        items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Wind: " + data.features[0].properties.Wind + "</li>");
        obj = $('<div>').append($( "<ul/>", { class: "my-new-list", html: items.join("") })).html();
        initMap();
    });
}
```

How would I go about adding a second $.getJSON to display the map marker from the URL in the JSON output, below?

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [-85.362709, 40.466442], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"24-hr Precip": "0.00", "Dewpoint": "26", "Pressure": "30.23", "Ptrend": "+", "Station": "KINHARTF10", "Temp": "30.2 F (-1.0 C)", "Time": "Last Updated on January 24, 12:56 PM EST", "Weather": "Overcast", "Wind": "From the SE at 4.5 MPH Gusting to 6.9 MPH", "icon": "cloudy",
        "icon_url": "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/cloudy.gif"}, "type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add lat and lng as parameters in your downloadJSON and "ajax/GeoObs.json?" example ajax/GeoObs.json?_=date&lat=xx&lng=xxx. ou have to add also "&lat=xx&lng=xxx" in your page and call "downloadJSON(lat,lng)" and create a second marker